# How do I query for the last 30 days of data in Power Query using JSON?

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to request the last 30 days of CrewHu Import data from today's date in this query. At the moment it is just set to get everything greater than the 25th September 2022 but I want to change this to be a dynamic value. Has anyone else had this problem / knows of a workaround?

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.crewhu.com/api" & "/v1/survey?query={""_updated_at"":{""$gte"":""2022-09-25T00:00:00.000Z""}}", [Headers=[X_CREWHU_APITOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxx"]])),
```

I've tried:

```
OneMonthAgo = Text.Replace(Text.Start (Text.From(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-30)),10),"/","-") & "T00:00:00.000Z",
```

And calling this as a variable but because the string does not come with quotation marks it gives a syntax error when the variable is called in the 'Source = ' line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you want

```
= Date.ToText(Date.From(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-30)), [Format="yyyy-MM-dd"])& "T00:00:00.000Z"
```

since that returns 2022-09-28T00:00:00.000Z while yours returns 9-28-2022 T00:00:00.000Z which does not seem to be the original format

then try out this, which I cant test

```
let variable = Date.ToText(Date.From(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-30)), [Format="yyyy-MM-dd"])& "T00:00:00.000Z",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.crewhu.com/api" & "/v1/survey?query={""_updated_at"":{""$gte"":"""&variable&"""}}", [Headers=[X_CREWHU_APITOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxx"]]))
in Source
```